# ¿Como hago para sumar estos valores?, adjunto el codigo

Tags: javascript, angular

Hola quisiera saber como hacer para poder sumar estos valores que obtengo al hacer un foreach y coger un elemento en especifico

```
this.cartProducts.forEach(element => {
        this.quantity = element.quantity;
        console.log(this.quantity);
        
      });
```

Esto es lo que obtengo por consola
[image: esto es lo que obtengo por consola]

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "coger un elemento en específico"?¿qué parámetro debe cumplirse para tomar dicho valor?

Comment: Solamente crea un sumador, es decir total =  total + elemento_a_sumar, o total += elemento_a_sumar

Comment: @JosueArriola me refiero al elemento quantity asi como esta en el codigo, es para poder obtener la suma total de todas las cantidades

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si defines la variable `total` podrías hacer algo como:

```
let total = 0;
this.cartProducts.forEach(element => {
    total += parseInt(element.quantity);//Parseo a int para evitar NaN
});
console.log(total);
```

Edit: He añadido el `parseInt` para evitar el error indicado en el comentario diciendo que le da NaN.

Comment: Cuando hago eso me sale que el valor de total es NaN

Comment: Si te sale eso @Luis entonces deberás probar haciendo cast de los valores

Comment: Como dijo @BetaM, es cuestión de pasar el valor a número. En tu consola te imprimía los números así que en teoría está cogiéndolos bien, solo que como string, supongo.

Comment: No amigo igual me sigue dicendo NaN, y aunque le haga el cast dice que es de tipo Number, la verdad ya busque por todos lados y no consegui solucion sencillamente evitare sumar esos elementos y hacer otra cosa, he estado teniendo puros problemas de este tipo sin soluciones desde que entre practicar con las sesiones de laravel :(. De verdad que les agradezco la ayuda